# having trouble with cloudshell and google sql

Tags: mysql

I set up a google sql mysql db yesterday and was able to login to the db via google shell, create some tables, add some data and run some queries. Great.

Today, I am getting:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@ .. ip address

I have tried resetting the password, adding new users via the cloud console, etc - but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: So I figured this out, and it was completely not intuitive.  At least for me, make sure that the setting for SSL connections under connections is set to:  Unsecured connections are allowed to connect to this instance.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, and it was completely not intuitive. At least for me, make sure that the setting for SSL connections under connections is set to: Unsecured connections are allowed to connect to this instance.